# Как сделать с помощью css обводку вокруг этой картинки, или же как создать такую форму с помощью css?

Tags: html, css

Есть две картинки-фона (свг). У них разные формы (неровные грани что ли). В обычном состоянии она с красной обводкой, а при наведении с белой. Не могу понять как так сделать с помощью clip-path или border-image.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чем svg не устраивает ?

Comment: svg как раз для этого нужен - не стандартные формы, анимации и прочее вместо кучи кода в css c линейными градиентами

Comment: я как раз не могу понять как с свг сделать

Comment: path d="" внутри между кавычками пишутся координаты но что бы не вникать в случае если у вас разовая задача то можете открыть illustrator и просто обвести эту фигуру и сохранить как svg

Comment: @MaximLensky Так а разве можно изменить path при наведении?

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/xxgYbpK при ховере что угодно можно сделать

Comment: @MaximLensky Извиняй, что достаю, но не мог бы ещё помочь...
Есть картинка и при наведении я вешаю на неё outline. Картинка со срезом внизу, а outline делает коробку. Как сделать так, чтобы outline был вместе со срезом? Хз как ещё объяснить...
https://imgur.com/a/kNqOerv

Comment: вы общий макет покажите - я или кто то другой сделают это хоть на css хоть на svg

Comment: @MaximLensky Данной картинки в принципе хватит - https://imgur.com/a/k7fG9Y6

Она без нижнего правого угла. Когда я даю outline: 10px solid #fff; то образуется просто квадрат вокруг картинки и что она без угла не учитывается...
Картинка должна быть не в svg, а png

Comment: в svg не outline а stroke это цвет обводки и stroke-width толщина обводки

Comment: @MaximLensky Я не хочу использовать svg. Когда вставлял код этой картинки, то там есть тег <image> и оооочень много строк от него. Хотелось бы без svg.

Comment: тогда позовите @Sevastopol' он пять сек сделает на html+css, я к сожалению люблю только svg и threejs

Comment: @Sevastopol' Сделайте пожалуйста на css+html)

Answer (score 7):

По просьбе автора вопроса - вариант CSS.

Такую рамку можно попробовать воспроизвести только с помощью градиентов, и это довольно просто. Один только минус - код получается великоватым. Залить готовую фигуру одним цветом с помощью градиентов также не сложно. Однако, в вопросе по картинке можно определить, что у заливки есть прозрачность. И вот здесь тогда уже возникают небольшие трудности - сделать это конечно возможно, но слишком трудоемко, и такая реализация не стоит затраченного времени. Вот пример с полностью готовой рамкой и для демонстрации частично залитым полупрозрачным цветом:

```css
body {padding: 20px; background: url(https://i.imgur.com/LmX45XA.jpeg); background-size: cover;}
span {font-size: 26px;}

div { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
  width: 300px; height: 300px;
  background:
   /*в 40 20 - 240*/
   linear-gradient(180deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*л 40 50 - 210*/
   linear-gradient(90deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px,  transparent 100%),
   /*пв 20 150 - 130*/
   linear-gradient(270deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*пн 30 30 150 - 110*/
   linear-gradient(270deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*нн 30 30 150 - 110*/
   linear-gradient(0deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*нв 30 20 150 - 100*/
   linear-gradient(0deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*увл*/
   linear-gradient(-225deg, transparent 28px, red 28px, red 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%),
   /*увп*/
   linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 14px, red 14px, red 16px, transparent 16px, transparent 100%),
   /*уп*/
   linear-gradient(-225deg, transparent 316px, red 316px, red 318px, transparent 318px, transparent 100%),
   /*унп*/
   linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 28px, red 28px, red 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%),
   /*унл*/
   linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 28px, red 28px, red 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%),
   /*унц*/
   linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 28px, red 28px, red 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%),
   /*bg*/
   linear-gradient(-225deg, transparent 30px, rgba(20,40,140,0.4) 30px, rgba(20,40,140,0.4) 178px, transparent 178px, transparent 100%);
   
   background-size: 240px 100%,
                    100% 210px,
                    100% 130px,
                    100% 110px,
                    110px 100%,
                    100px calc(100% - 20px),
                    100% 100%,
                    100% 100%,
                    100% 169px,
                    20px 100%,
                    30px 100%,
                    20px 100%,
                    100% 100%;
                    
   background-position: 40px 0,
                        0 40px,
                        0 20px,
                        -20px 169px,
                        150px 0,
                        30px 0,
                        0 0,
                        0 0,
                        0 0,
                        calc(100% - 20px) 20px,
                        0 calc(100% - 10px),
                        130px 20px,
                        0 0;
                        
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div><span>Какой-то текст</span></div>
```

Чтобы решить вопрос по заливке фигуры полупрозрачным цветом, можно добавить еще один элемент и воспользоваться свойством `clip-path: polygon()`. С помощью этого свойства мы "обрежем" фигуру нужной нам формы и зальем ее цветом. Вот что у нас получилось:

```css
body {padding: 20px; background: url(https://i.imgur.com/LmX45XA.jpeg); background-size: cover;}
span {font-size: 26px;}

.item { display: flex; width: 300px; height: 300px;
  background:
   /*в 40 20 - 240*/
   linear-gradient(180deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*л 40 50 - 210*/
   linear-gradient(90deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px,  transparent 100%),
   /*пв 20 150 - 130*/
   linear-gradient(270deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*пн 30 30 150 - 110*/
   linear-gradient(270deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*нн 30 30 150 - 110*/
   linear-gradient(0deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*нв 30 20 150 - 100*/
   linear-gradient(0deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*увл*/
   linear-gradient(-225deg, transparent 28px, red 28px, red 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%),
   /*увп*/
   linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 14px, red 14px, red 16px, transparent 16px, transparent 100%),
   /*уп*/
   linear-gradient(-225deg, transparent 316px, red 316px, red 318px, transparent 318px, transparent 100%),
   /*унп*/
   linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 28px, red 28px, red 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%),
   /*унл*/
   linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 28px, red 28px, red 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%),
   /*унц*/
   linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 28px, red 28px, red 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%);
   
   background-size: 240px 100%,
                    100% 210px,
                    100% 130px,
                    100% 110px,
                    110px 100%,
                    100px calc(100% - 20px),
                    100% 100%,
                    100% 100%,
                    100% 169px,
                    20px 100%,
                    30px 100%,
                    20px 100%;
                    
   background-position: 40px 0,
                        0 40px,
                        0 20px,
                        -20px 169px,
                        150px 0,
                        30px 0,
                        0 0,
                        0 0,
                        0 0,
                        calc(100% - 20px) 20px,
                        0 calc(100% - 10px),
                        130px 20px;
                        
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.item>div { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
  width: 300px; height: 300px; background: rgba(20,40,140,0.4);
  clip-path: polygon(40px 0, 280px 0,
                     300px 20px, 300px 150px, 280px 170px, 280px 280px,
                     260px 300px, 150px 300px, 130px 280px, 30px 280px,
                     0 250px, 0 42px);
}
```

```html
<div class="item"><div><span>Какой-то текст</span></div></div>
```

Добавим эффект при наведении:

```css
body {padding: 20px; background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95) 100%), url(https://i.imgur.com/qaYq4fG.jpg); background-size: cover;}
span {font-size: 26px; z-index: 3; color: white;}

.item { display: flex; position: relative; justify-content: center; align-items: center; z-index: 1;
  width: 300px; height: 300px; background: rgba(20,40,140,0.4);
  clip-path: polygon(40px 0, 280px 0,
                     300px 20px, 300px 150px, 280px 170px, 280px 280px,
                     260px 300px, 150px 300px, 130px 280px, 30px 280px,
                     0 250px, 0 40px);
}

.item::before {content: ""; display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 300px; height: 300px; z-index: 2;
  background:
   /*в 40 20 - 240*/
   linear-gradient(180deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*л 40 50 - 210*/
   linear-gradient(90deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px,  transparent 100%),
   /*пв 20 150 - 130*/
   linear-gradient(270deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*пн 30 30 150 - 110*/
   linear-gradient(270deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*нн 30 30 150 - 110*/
   linear-gradient(0deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*нв 30 20 150 - 100*/
   linear-gradient(0deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*увл*/
   linear-gradient(-225deg, transparent 28px, red 28px, red 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%),
   /*увп*/
   linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 14px, red 14px, red 16px, transparent 16px, transparent 100%),
   /*уп*/
   linear-gradient(-225deg, transparent 316px, red 316px, red 318px, transparent 318px, transparent 100%),
   /*унп*/
   linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 28px, red 28px, red 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%),
   /*унл*/
   linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 28px, red 28px, red 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%),
   /*унц*/
   linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 28px, red 28px, red 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%);
   
   background-size: 240px 100%,
                    100% 210px,
                    100% 130px,
                    100% 110px,
                    110px 100%,
                    100px calc(100% - 20px),
                    100% 100%,
                    100% 100%,
                    100% 169px,
                    20px 100%,
                    30px 100%,
                    20px 100%;
                    
   background-position: 40px 0,
                        0 40px,
                        0 20px,
                        -20px 169px,
                        150px 0,
                        30px 0,
                        0 0,
                        0 0,
                        0 0,
                        calc(100% - 20px) 20px,
                        0 calc(100% - 10px),
                        130px 20px;
                        
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   opacity: 1;
   transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.item::after {content: ""; display: block; position: absolute; top: 2px; left: 2px; width: 296px; height: 296px; z-index: 2;
  background:
   /*в 40 20 - 240*/
   linear-gradient(180deg, white, white 6px, transparent 6px, transparent 100%),
   /*л 40 50 - 210*/
   linear-gradient(90deg, white, white 6px, transparent 6px,  transparent 100%),
   /*пв 20 150 - 130*/
   linear-gradient(270deg, white, white 6px, transparent 6px, transparent 100%),
   /*пн 30 30 150 - 110*/
   linear-gradient(270deg, white, white 6px, transparent 6px, transparent 100%),
   /*нн 30 30 150 - 110*/
   linear-gradient(0deg, white, white 6px, transparent 6px, transparent 100%),
   /*нв 30 20 150 - 100*/
   linear-gradient(0deg, white, white 6px, transparent 6px, transparent 100%),
   /*увл*/
   linear-gradient(-225deg, transparent 27px, white 27px, white 33px, transparent 33px, transparent 100%),
   /*увп*/
   linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 13px, white 13px, white 19px, transparent 19px, transparent 100%),
   /*уп*/
   linear-gradient(-225deg, transparent 310px, white 310px, white 316px, transparent 316px, transparent 100%),
   /*унп*/
   linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 28px, white 28px, white 34px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%),
   /*унл*/
   linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 28px, white 28px, white 34px, transparent 34px, transparent 100%),
   /*унц*/
   linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 30px, white 30px, white 36px, transparent 32px, transparent 100%);
   
   background-size: 236px 100%,
                    100% 206px,
                    100% 126px,
                    100% 110px,
                    106px 100%,
                    100px calc(100% - 20px),
                    100% 100%,
                    100% 100%,
                    100% 170px,
                    26px 100%,
                    30px 100%,
                    22px 100%;
                    
   background-position: 40px 0,
                        0 40px,
                        0 20px,
                        -20px 164px,
                        150px 0,
                        30px 0,
                        0 0,
                        0 0,
                        0 -5px,
                        calc(100% - 20px) 20px,
                        0 calc(100% - 9px),
                        130px 24px;
                        
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   filter: blur(1px);
   opacity: 0;
   transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}

.item:hover::before {
  filter: blur(1px);
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}
.item:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"><span>Какой-то текст</span></div>
```

Обводка белого цвета при наведении получилась правда с мелкими дефектами на стыках, поэтому нужна точная подгонка, а на это требуется больше времени. Но, думаю, автор вопроса сможет дальше разобраться самостоятельно, ничего сложного в этом нет.

---

**UPD/** Поправил мелкие дефекты. Максимально постарался приблизить эффект при наведении на тот, что на картинке. Получилось не идеально, но автор извиняй, лучше всего для создания подобных фигур все же воспользоваться SVG.

```css
body {padding: 20px; background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 100%), url(https://i.imgur.com/qaYq4fG.jpg); background-size: cover;}

.item { display: flex; position: relative; justify-content: center; align-items: center; z-index: 1;
  width: 320px; height: 320px;
  clip-path: polygon(40px 0, 300px 0,
                     320px 20px, 320px 160px, 300px 180px, 300px 300px,
                     280px 320px, 160px 320px, 140px 300px, 30px 300px,
                     0 270px, 0 40px);
}

.item::before {content: ""; display: block; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; width: 300px; height: 300px; z-index: 2;
  background:
   /*1. в*/
   linear-gradient(180deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*2. л*/
   linear-gradient(90deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px,  transparent 100%),
   /*3. пв*/
   linear-gradient(270deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*4. пн*/
   linear-gradient(270deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*5. нн*/
   linear-gradient(0deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*6. нв*/
   linear-gradient(0deg, red, red 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%),
   /*7. увл*/
   linear-gradient(-225deg, transparent 28px, red 28px, red 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%),
   /*8. увп*/
   linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 14px, red 14px, red 16px, transparent 16px, transparent 100%),
   /*9. уп*/
   linear-gradient(-225deg, transparent 316px, red 316px, red 318px, transparent 318px, transparent 100%),
   /*10. унп*/
   linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 28px, red 28px, red 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%),
   /*11. унл*/
   linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 28px, red 28px, red 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%),
   /*12. унц*/
   linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 28px, red 28px, red 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 100%);
   
   background-size: 240px 100%,
                    100% 210px,
                    100% 130px,
                    100% 110px,
                    110px 100%,
                    100px calc(100% - 20px),
                    100% 100%,
                    100% 100%,
                    100% 169px,
                    20px 100%,
                    30px 100%,
                    20px 100%;
                    
   background-position: 40px 0,
                        0 40px,
                        0 20px,
                        -20px 169px,
                        150px 0,
                        30px 0,
                        0 0,
                        0 0,
                        0 0,
                        calc(100% - 20px) 20px,
                        0 calc(100% - 10px),
                        130px 20px;
                        
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   opacity: 1;
   transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.item::after {content: ""; display: block; position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 8px; width: 310px; height: 310px; z-index: 1;
clip-path: polygon(40px 0, 290px 0,
                     310px 20px, 310px 160px, 300px 160px, 290px 290px,
                     257px 307px, 160px 310px, 138px 298px, 30px 284px,
                     0 260px, 0 40px);
  background:
   /*1. в*/
   linear-gradient(180deg, white, white 6px, transparent 6px, transparent 100%),
   /*2. л*/
   linear-gradient(90deg, white, white 6px, transparent 6px,  transparent 100%),
   /*3. пв*/
   linear-gradient(270deg, white, white 6px, transparent 6px, transparent 100%),
   /*4. пн*/
   linear-gradient(270deg, white, white 6px, transparent 6px, transparent 100%),
   /*5. нн*/
   linear-gradient(0deg, white, white 6px, transparent 6px, transparent 100%),
   /*6. нв*/
   linear-gradient(0deg, white, white 6px, transparent 6px, transparent 100%),
   /*7. увл*/
   linear-gradient(-225deg, transparent 27px, white 27px, white 34px, transparent 34px, transparent 100%),
   /*8. увп*/
   linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 13px, white 13px, white 19px, transparent 19px, transparent 100%),
   /*9. уп*/
   linear-gradient(-225deg, transparent 310px, white 310px, white 316px, transparent 316px, transparent 100%),
   /*10. унп*/
   linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 29px, white 29px, white 35px, transparent 35px, transparent 100%),
   /*11. унл*/
   linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 28px, white 28px, white 34px, transparent 34px, transparent 100%),
   /*12. унц*/
   linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 30px, white 30px, white 36px, transparent 32px, transparent 100%);
   
   background-size: 246px 100%,
                    100% 212px,
                    100% 130px,
                    100% 116px,
                    116px 100%,
                    100px calc(100% - 20px),
                    100% 100%,
                    100% 100%,
                    100% 156px,/**/
                    22px 100%,
                    32px 100%,
                    20px 100%;
                    
   background-position: 40px 0,
                        0 40px,
                        -6px 20px,
                        -26px 168px,
                        148px -6px,
                        30px -6px,
                        0 0,
                        -6px -1px,
                        -6px 14px,/**/
                        calc(100% - 26px) 16px,
                        0 calc(100% - 16px),
                        130px 18px;
                        
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   filter: blur(0px);
   opacity: 0;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.item:hover::before {
  filter: blur(3px);
  transform: scale(1.03);
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
}
.item:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

span {
  z-index: -1; display: block; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px;
  width: 300px; height: 300px;
  font-size: 26px; color: white; text-align: center; line-height: 300px; background: rgba(20,40,140,0.4);
  clip-path: polygon(40px 0, 280px 0,
                     300px 20px, 300px 150px, 280px 170px, 280px 280px,
                     260px 300px, 150px 300px, 130px 280px, 30px 280px,
                     0 250px, 0 40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="item"><span>Какой-то текст</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.4;
  background-image: repeating-radial-gradient( circle at 0 0, transparent 0, #000000 20px), repeating-linear-gradient( #444cf755, #444cf7);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" overflow="visible" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="19" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="475.5,319.5 510.5,289.5 1017,289.5 
    1028.5,299.5 1028.5,543.8 1006.5,562.5 1005.5,768.5 982.5,790.5 745.5,790.5 731.5,776.5 491.5,776.5 475.5,761.6 "/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Если нужен css, то можно преобразовать svg в css url:

```css
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Cdiv%3E%3C%3Fxml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'%3F%3E%3Csvg version='1.2' baseProfile='tiny' id='Слой_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 1920 1080' overflow='visible' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cpolygon fill='none' stroke='%23FFFFFF' stroke-width='19' stroke-miterlimit='10' points='475.5,319.5 510.5,289.5 1017,289.5 1028.5,299.5 1028.5,543.8 1006.5,562.5 1005.5,768.5 982.5,790.5 745.5,790.5 731.5,776.5 491.5,776.5 475.5,761.6 '/%3E%3C/svg%3E%3C/div%3E");
```

Comment: в комментариях написано же - что автор не хочет использовать svg

Comment: @MaximLensky, я же добавил вариант на css